# Dual boot install and re-partitioning to use mbr2gpt tool

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot, mbr, gpt

I now have Windows 10 Pro, build 17134.

I want to create dual boot for Ubuntu 18.04.

I want to use MBR2GPT.exe tool because now my BIOS mode is "Legacy" (MBR).

Requirement is to have only 3 partitions to use MBR2GPT.exe tool.

My problem is I have 4 partitions. How to solve?

[image: my-diskmanagement-image]

Thank you everybody for helping and sorry my English.

Comment: Is your BIOS capable of booting in UEFI mode? Have you confirmed that? Have you confirmed if the disk is currently GPT or MBR? Disk Mgmt --> Right Click the Disk 0 --> Properties --> Volumes tab

Comment: @pat2015 yes, BIOS capable in UEFI mode. Disk currently in MBR. Thank you.

Comment: In that case one possible approach could be to delete the HP recovery partition 1. Take backup of your critical data. 2. Using appropriate HP tools create a recovery USB pen drive for your existing HP computer/laptop’s Windows 10. Follow manufacturer recommended procedure/tools to do the same. So that it worst case scenario you can restore your Windows 10 from the recovery USB. Now after creation of recovery USB, delete the HP recovery partition. You have 12 GB of free space and 3 primary partitions. Now run the tool convert to GPT. You can even exercise Validate option before any conversion.

Comment: You will find that an EFI partition shall be created. Set the boot mode to UEFI in BIOS and hopefully Windows shall boot in UEFI Mode. Now shrink the Windows 10 system drive and create free space for Ubuntu.

Comment: @pat2015 thank you for approach. It is difficult, I will study your answer in detail and then trying execute same you said.

Comment: @pat2015 - and what if i do not care about my current windows 10 installation? meaning i want to start clean from zero: moving from MBR to GPT and then windows 10 pro + ubuntu 18.04, how would i do steps for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is in response to the comment made by OP

> ‘ what if i do not care about my current windows 10 installation?
>   meaning i want to start clean from zero: moving from MBR to GPT and
>   then windows 10 pro + ubuntu 18.04, how would i do steps for that?’

If you have any important personal data on C: e.g. your MyDocuments folders or any other personal folders that you have created and populated with your files, then back it up first. You will lose it during clean install.

Also if manufacturer has provided any drivers for Windows 10, download the same from their website for later installation.

If you do not care about your current Windows installation and you want to do a clean install then all you need is a Windows 10 installer USB or DVD. I assume your current Windows 10 is activated and registered with MS Servers. If you do not have Windows 10 DVD or ISO file, you can download one from the Microsoft using Media Creation Tool.

[Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10)

You may either download the ISO file or create a USB pen drive installer using Media Creation Tool on the fly. If you download ISO then use a third party tool like [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en_IE.html) to create a bootable USB Pen drive. Select GPT Partition Scheme for UEFI Computer and FAT32 format in the options. To do all above steps, you need a working Windows PC, so use your current one for the same and the pen drive should be more than 4GB.

- Boot your PC using  Windows 10 USB Pen drive.
- When Windows 10 Installer loads, select your language and region and click Next
- Select `Repair Your Computer`

[image]

- Select Troubleshoot --> Command Prompt
- Type in `DISKPART` at the command prompt
- type `LIST DISK`
- It will list the disks. You will also see your pen drive disk therein.
- Now carefully select your system disk. The command is `SELECT DISK 0` Note 0 is the number of the system disk here that you wish to clean and do a fresh install. See the below screenshot. Generally this number is 0 but it may be different in your case. So carefully select the disk here.

[image]

- Now type `CLEAN`  This quickly deletes all the partitions permanently. Disk will be clean.
- Now type `CONVERT GPT`

See the below screenshot.

[image]

- Now just to confirm that disk has been converted to GPT type `LIST DISK`

[image]

- Exit, Exit the Windows 10 setup and restart the PC and go to BIOS. Now Set the boot mode to UEFI.
- Now boot your computer using the Windows 10 USB pen drive
- Click Install Now button
- Since you are reinstalling Windows 10, select 'I don't have a product key'
- Select Custom Install
- Create a Partition of your preferred size. Preferably at least 50 -60 GB for System drive.
  [image]
- Complete the Windows 10 installation till it lands at the Desktop. Then install all applicable drivers and when connected to the Internet your copy of Windows shall get activated again using Digital Entitlement from the MS Servers.
- Create a USB Installer for Ubuntu using Rufus.
- Boot your PC using that Ubuntu USB Installer
- Select free space or create partitions for Ubuntu in the free space
- When it reboots go to BIOS and select Ubuntu Entry to complete the installation if required. Respective OS's will put their EFI Bootloaders in respective folders on EFI Partition.
- Now to make your life easier, you can use third party boot manager like [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) to present you with boot option choices when you start your PC.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is fantastic answer, so detailed and so clear, thank you mister. i give all my points for your answer.